# Image generated using buildroot, VC4 fails to detect hdmi

Tags: opengles, buildroot

I had built a raspberry pi4 64bit image using buildroot (latest LTS release). I see it's booting with 5.10.x kernel, however vc4 driver does not detect HDMI. Upon `modprobe vc4.ko` I see these logs.

```
[  797.913512] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[  797.920201] [drm:vc4_hdmi_bind [vc4]] Failed to get ddc i2c adapter by node
```

This is the corresponding failure point in driver -
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.10.y/drivers/gpu/drm/vc4/vc4_hdmi.c#L3200